# rails and foundation: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm using rails, this is the full error. Any help is appreciated.

```
File to import not found or unreadable: util/util.
Load path: /Users/[user_name]/...
on line 42 of app/assets/stylesheets/_settings.scss
from line 3 of ./app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss

37: @include foundation-slider;
....
```

Comment: Are you using the foundation gem or are you using a CDN hosted version of foundation?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Have you tried running ``bundle exec rake assets:precompile``?

Comment: No but I just did now and am getting the same error

Comment: Check out this link: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/37602-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-utilutil or post your problem in the foundation forum: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum

Answer (score 8):

You only have to restart the server (in the terminal : ctrl + c to quite the server and than run 'rails s') 
For me, it resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

If restarting the rails server didn't work, you might have an older one still running in the background.

To check this, run `ps aux | grep spring` to list all running Spring servers. A running Spring server will have as the last three columns `spring server | YourApp | started X hours ago`.

If you find one, note down the 4-5 digit number in the second column (the number immediately following your user account name), and run `kill -9 X`, where `X` is that number.

This should kill that server running in the background, and when you start a new server with `rails s`, the problem should be resolved.